# Use Model from inside a Library cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I created a few files in app/Lib folder and would like to access one of my models from the library classes:

```
<?php 

App::uses('CrawlerBase','Lib');
App::uses('Deal', 'Model');

class SampleCrawler extends CrawlerBase {

    public $uses = array('Deal');

    function __construct(){
          $this->Deal->create();
```

However, cake cant seems to find the Deal model and im getting a call to member function create() on a non-object in the model creation line.

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Other way to also do this:

```
APP::import('Model', 'Deal');
$this->Deal = new Deal();

$this->Deal->create();
```

Comment: App::import is not used in 2.x anymore for anything except Vendor loading. If anything, use App::uses() for loading (internal) classes. But I would always prefer ClassRegistry::init() for model loading.

Answer (score 9):

Always include models manually if not in a controller/shell:

```
$this->Deal = ClassRegistry::init('Deal');
```

and then

```
$this->Deal->create(); // etc
```

The advantage: You let Cake load and init the model for you, so if you already did that earlier it will try to reuse it.

EDIT: for the sake of completeness, inside a controller/shell you can simply do

```
$this->loadModel('Deal');
$this->Deal->create();
```

Comment: ClassRegistry must first be called with App::uses('ClassRegistry', 'Utility');

Answer (score 0):

Try;

```
$deal = new Deal(); // to create Deal Object

//if that doesnot work then, do
ClassRegistry::init("Deal");
$deal = new Deal();
```